# TypeScript Agent Name is already created

Tags: c#, typescript

In the agent controller I have add logic to check if the agent name exists and to return a resultWarning message. The part that I am not sure about is the AgentManager.ts when I debug it I do get the result warning message returned but at the callback response? I like to alert the user that the name is already created.

> Should I return a BadRequest object or is there a better way to do this?

AgentManager.ts

```
saveAgentWithAgentInformation(agent: AgentModel, callback: Function) {
        var promise = (typeof agent.Id === "undefined" || agent.Id === null || agent.Id === 0) ?
            this.agentsService.createAgent(agent) :
            this.agentsService.updateAgentWithAgentInformation(agent);

        this.viewManager.busyIndicator.show();
        promise.then((response) => {
            callback(response);
        })
            .fail((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                this.notificationManager.error(response.responseJSON.Message);
            })
            .always(() => {
                this.viewManager.busyIndicator.hide();
            });
    }
```

Agent Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
            [ApplicationApiAuthorize("Administrator, ContentManager")]
            public IHttpActionResult CreateAgent([FromBody]AgentModel agentModel)
            {
                LogHelper.Info($"Creating agent {agentModel.Name}");


                //Search if Agent name is in the system
                bool flgAgent = AgentsDataService.AgentExists(agentModel.Name);

                if (flgAgent == false)
                {
                    var agentEntity = new Agent();
                    Mapper.DynamicMap(agentModel, agentEntity);

                    var agentInformationEntities = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AgentInformation>>(agentModel.AgentInformations);
                    agentEntity.AgentInformations = new EntitySet<AgentInformation>();
                    agentEntity.AgentInformations.AddRange(agentInformationEntities);

                    var operationResult = AgentsDataService.InsertAgent(agentEntity);                        

                    var result = Ok(new
                    {
                        Value = Mapper.Map<AgentModel>(operationResult)
                    });
                    return result;
                }else
                {
                    var resultWarning = $"Agent Name '{agentModel.Name}' is already used";
                    //return Json(resultWarning);
                    return BadRequest(resultWarning);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request itself is fine, so returning BadRequest seems inappropriate. I'd look more at 409 (Conflict), that seems to be the code for this situation:

> https://httpstatuses.com/409
>
> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource. This code is used in situations
>   where the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the
>   request.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely shouldn't return BadRequest in this case. The best choice would be `Unprocessable Entity`.

> 422 Unprocessable Entity response status code indicates that the
>   server understands the content type of the request entity, and the
>   syntax of the request entity is correct, but it was unable to process
>   the contained instructions.

Comment: I dont see 422 in the list https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netframework-4.8